# Vlookup error thrown when trying to delete the columns

Tags: excel, csv, vlookup

I had used vlookup for matching the column values. However after vlookup i dont need the column used for vlookup. But when i tried to delete the column the vlookup column value changed to #REF!. How should i achieve without affecting the matched data? I had tried to copy to another excel sheet but doesnt work. Any idea pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are saying you have a column (A) that is doing a vlookup on another column (B). You want to delete column B but have the results of the vlookup remain in column A.. Can be achieved by copy pasting the results in column A as values before you delete column B. So perform the vlookup, select the cells with the results, copy then click paste special and choose values